# Graph Theory Contest Maths

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math

I have never covered Graph Theory so I've been put into a bit of a quandary over how to do these two questions (I am assuming the second is graph theory, if not I will edit it out of the question).

How should I approach these questions, where do I start? I have no access to the solutions for these problems, but because they are pitched at a high school level I assume no 'complex' mathematics is required.

> 1) A graph has 15 vertices. There is at most one edge between each pair of vertices, and no edge connects a vertex to itself. Each edge is coloured red or blue so that there no monochromatic triangles. Find the largest possible number of edges of this graph.
>
> 2) Three travel companies operate a transport network between n cities. The transport between each pair of cities is a monopoly of one travel company. Prove that, if $n\geq 11$, there must be a round trip through 4 cities with each journey organised by the same company, but this is not necessarily the case if $n \leq 10$

Comment: The 2nd question translates to given n nodes where there is an edge between each pair which is either red blue or green show there is a cycle of length 4 using the same colour for the edges in the cycle for n>10. Then show it doesn't always hold for graphs with 10 or less nodes

Answer (score 1):

For problem $1$ the graph cannot contain a $K_6$. The graph with the most edges  on $15$ vertices that does not contain a $K_6$ is the graph $K_{3,3,3,3,3}$ by Turan's theorem. This graph can be colored so it contains no monochromatic triangles.

To see how first try to color the edges of $K_5$ so that it does not contain a monochromatic triangle. And then identify each of the parts of $K_{3,3,3,3,3}$ with a vertex of $K_5$. Then color an edge between part $1$ and part $2$ with the color you used for that edge when you colored $K_5$.

Comment: What does $K_i$ stand for? Would there be a way to answer this question without 'Turan's theorem'? Like I said I've never studied graph theory before. If there isn't a way, can you recommend material for graph theory at contest level. Also, could you hazard a guess at how difficult these questions are (like AMC 10 up to IMO I guess if you are in the US) I was given them without context.

Comment: probably like the level of an easy second problem in the IMO. Also $K_i$ is the complete graph on $i$ vertices. [Book 1](http://www.amazon.com/Problem-Solving-Methods-Combinatorics-Approach-Olympiad/dp/3034805969/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1421101347&sr=8-1&keywords=pablo+soberon) [Book 2](http://www.amazon.com/Problems-Combinatorics-Discrete-Mathematics-Optimization/dp/0471801550/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1421101369&sr=8-5&keywords=tomescu) , [book 3](http://www.amazon.com/102-Combinatorial-Problems-Titu-Andreescu/dp/0817643176/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1421101398&sr=8-1&keywords=102+problems)

Comment: Would you say a good grasp of Graph Theory (and the contents of those books) is an essential pre-requisite for these types of problems? Would intuition and reasonable deduction not be enough? If so I might have to shelve these questions for a while.

Comment: I'd say Turan is the only important theorem that appears often.

Comment: But there are many small results that can be useful.